# classes.jar not getting generated in .aar file

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I am using Android Studio AI-141.216xxx.
I generated a .aar file from FFMPEG module/library from this project:
https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java

I then tried to import a .aar locally into a module in some other application.
imports were failing.
But, when I checked in the 'generated' folder, 
I see that classes.jar is empty.

Would you know why this is happening? Any pointer is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried my answer?

Comment: Thanks @JaredBurrows but it didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

You have your project setup as an app: https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java/blob/master/app/build.gradle#L1

**Change:**

`apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`

**To:**

`apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`

And Your build is failing on Travis build is failing.

Comment: I did change plugin from application to library; but classes.jar is still missing from generated aar file.

Answer (score 0):

For me, updating the module's `buildToolsVersion` fixed it.

The build was working fine in Android Studio 2.1. I updated to 2.2 and started experiencing this issue.

Took build tools from `23.0.3` to `24.0.2` and the build was restored.